# Contradictory axioms

Tags: axioms

¿Do you know if there is any mathematical theory (or axiomatic theory) whose axioms, or at least one of them, contradict with other axioms of another theory?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you mean like whether you assume the axiom of choice or not?

Comment: No, because, if I am not mistaken, the axiom of choice is not contradicted by any other axiom of any other theory.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry